# scheduler produces empty files

Tags: python-2.7, pythonanywhere

I'm using pythonanywhere for a simple scheduled task.
I want to download data from a link once a day and save csv files. Later once i have a decent time series I'll figure out how I actually want to manage the data. It's not much data so don't need anything fancy like a database.

My script takes the data from the google sheets link, adds a log column and a time column, then writes a csv with the date in the filename.

It works exactly as I want it to when I run it manually in pythonanywhere, but the scheduler is just creating empty csv files albeit with the correct name.

Any ideas what's up? I don't understand the log file. Surely the error should happen when it is run manually?

script:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
import datetime

def write_today(df):
    date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    df.to_csv('Properties_'+date+'.csv')


url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19h2GmLN-2CLgk79gVxcazxtKqS6rwW36YA-qvuzEpG4/export?format=xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(url, header=1).rename(columns={'Unnamed: 1':'code'})
source = pd.read_excel(url).columns[0]
df['source'] = source
df['time'] = datetime.datetime.now()
write_today(df)
```

the scheduler is set up as so:
[image]

log file:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abmoore/load_data.py", line 24, in <module>
    write_today(df)
  File "/home/abmoore/load_data.py", line 16, in write_today
    df.to_csv('Properties_'+date+'.csv')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 1344, in to_csv
    formatter.save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/formats/format.py", line 1551, in save
    self._save()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/formats/format.py", line 1638, in _save
    self._save_header()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas/formats/format.py", line 1634, in _save_header
    writer.writerow(encoded_labels)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem there is the UnicodeDecodeError --  you have some non-ascii data in your spreadsheet, and the pandas `to_csv` function defaults to ascii encoding.  try specifying utf8 instead:

```
def write_today(df):
    filename = 'Properties_{date}.csv'.format(date=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
    df.to_csv(filename, encoding='utf8')
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html